# Reducing size of the image at Client Side in javascript before form submission

Tags: javascript, html, form-submit, filereader, image-resizing

Im trying to reduce the size of the image after reading at client side, the javascript code is as below, I'm getting two issues here 
1) The image preview is not showing up on the img id "img-upload"
2) The file that is being submitted via form submission "reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0])" is not the reduced size one.

I did try changing code to move the reader inside the image onload and then pass e.target.files[0] but that didn't work either.

Pls advise how I can resize and then send it via form submission to my backend.

```
function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();  

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                        $('#img-upload').attr('src', e.target.result);
                        img.onload = function () {
                            var MAX_WIDTH = 100;
                            var MAX_HEIGHT = 100;
                            var width = img.width;
                            var height = img.height;

                            if (width > height) {
                               if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                                  height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                                  width = MAX_WIDTH;
                               }
                            } else {
                               if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                                  width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                                  height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                               }
                            }

                            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                            canvas.width = width;
                            canvas.height = height;
                            canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(this, 0, 0, width, height);

                            img.src = e.target.result;
                            $('#img-upload').append(img);
                        }  

                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

            }
        }
```

Comment: what does your `img` variable points to

Answer (score 1):

Your code is creating an infinite call to `img.onload`
because of this

`img.src = e.target.result;` statement inside onload.

Beside this you are not reading the resized image from the canvas.

You can do this the following way

`canvas.toDataURL('image/png');`

**SNIPPET**

```js
var img = $('#img-upload')[0];
var show = $('#show')[0];

function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      debugger;
      $('#img-upload').attr('src', e.target.result);
      img.onload = function() {
        var MAX_WIDTH = 100;
        var MAX_HEIGHT = 100;
        var width = img.width;
        var height = img.height;

        if (width > height) {
          if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
            height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
            width = MAX_WIDTH;
          }
        } else {
          if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
            width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
            height = MAX_HEIGHT;
          }
        }

        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(this, 0, 0, width, height);

        //Causing Infinite Loop in your code
        //img.src = e.target.result; 
        
        // Get dataURL of resized image from canvas  
        show.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

      }

    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" onchange="readURL(this)">
<img id="img-upload">
<img id="show">
```

Comment: @Kaiido there is another assignment to  `img.src = e.target.result;` inside onload of the `img` check the code in the question. 

I have removed that part of the code in my solution.

Comment: Ho! you are right apologies. I stopped parsing at the first error I found... and he is appending an imahe to what should already be an image..

Comment: @NadirLaskar There is a problem. original image has 24 bit deph, but resized image has 42 bit deph, so resized image size is equal original image. how can you keep original image bit deph?